# Is Queen Elizabeth queuing for a sandwich in this photo?

Tags: united-kingdom, photography

[image]

Found it floating around Facebook with comments praising the queen for behaving like ordinary people.

Did the Queen Elizabeth actually queue for a sandwich in this photo? Or something else is happening?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The image is a real<sup>1</sup> image of a cardboard Queen. (http://www.bz-berlin.de/berlin/die-queen-macht-ueberall-in-berlin-eine-gute-figur).

That reference mentions "von Pappe", [which means "of cardboard"](https://translate.google.com/#de/en/von%20pappe), and in context ("nicht von Pappe") may be a pun.

Regardless of what that actually means, the reference also contains these photos, which clearly show what appears to me to be a cardboard stand:

[image]

[image]

<sup>1. I haven't found evidence eliminating the possibility of cosmetic digital post-processing.</sup>

Answer (score 43):

No, the Queen isn't queuing for a sandwich in this photo. It turns out be a cardboard cutout of Queen Elizabeth II or a photoshopped image. Several images were [posted on Berlin.de](http://www.bz-berlin.de/berlin/die-queen-macht-ueberall-in-berlin-eine-gute-figur) on June 23, 2015 16:43. They were attributed to photographer Charles Yunck.

According to [Berlin.de](http://www.bz-berlin.de/berlin/die-queen-macht-ueberall-in-berlin-eine-gute-figur),

> *Origin:* B.Z. war mit der Queen quer durch Berlin unterwegs. Die **89**-Jährige ist eben nicht **von Pappe** und macht überall eine Top-Figur.
>
> *Translation:* BZ was with the Queen through Berlin go. The **89**-year-old is not simply of **cardboard** and cuts a great figure.

Some other variants are below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Also another video was [found](http://www.bz-berlin.de/berlin/die-queen-macht-ueberall-in-berlin-eine-gute-figur), indicating that it is a cardboard cutout:

[image]

While searching, I found a high quality version of the image [here](http://static.bz-berlin.de/data/uploads/2015/06/138406151_6e8824685a-1920x1080.jpeg), zooming in:

[image]